# (click) with a ngFor Variable

Tags: angular

I'm trying to execute a function from a variable the following way:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let c of content">
            <div class="content-box" [style.background-color]="c.color" [matTooltip]="c.name" (click)="c.select"> 
            .....
```

My content:

```
this.content = [
      {name: '...',data: 13, code: 23, color: 'gray', select: 'testFunction()'},
      ....
      ];
```

Is this possible?

**Update 1**
My `test.component`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.user$ = this.store.pipe(select(currentUser));

    this.content = [
      {name: '...',data: 13, code: 23, color: 'gray', select: 'testFunction'},
      ....
    ];
  }

  testFunction() {
    console.log("Test.");

  }
```

Comment: Where does `testFunction` reside?

Comment: @yurzui where the `this.content` resides

Comment: No. First because that wouldn't call the function (you would need `c.select()`, and second because the select property is not a function, but a string. If it was a function, then sure you could call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try accessing method through square brackets:

**html**

```
(click)="this[c.select]()"
```

**ts**

```
@Component({...})
class SomeComponent {
  content = [
   {name: '...',..., select: 'testFunction'},
  ];

  testFunction() {
    console.log('test clicked');
  }
}
```

Comment: Got this console error:  `_co[_v.context.$implicit.select] is not a function`

Comment: This means that you don't have `testFunction` method defined in your component

Comment: Impossible. I updated the question with my component.

Comment: My mistake, miss-spelled the function, thanks! Is it possible to pass parameters?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can define `selectParams` and pass it

Comment: while this answer probably works, i don't think this is the correct way to do this.  Its unclear code and doesn't promote good practices.  I recommended an answer below.  I don't mind about the rep points but if you haven't tried it, please do.    It's the better and most common approach to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`select: 'testFunction()'` should be just `select: testFunction`.  You don't want the brackets or the single quotes.  Specifying it how you have makes it a string, not a function.

As well as that i think you need to do `c.select()` on the click property.